# adding random typography to div elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

i have the following code, that randomizes text from an array.

However what im not sure how to do the following.

1. display the result on browser load instead of onclick.
2. display the output to a div CLASS on load (so if i have multiple divs called "output", a random font/size/weight will be displayed in each div)
3. it should take the font from each div element and change the classes etc, instead of using the font names etc.
4. instead of using the font names in an array, how do i point each variable to a class? 

   .font1 {font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;}
   .font2 {font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
   .font3 {font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
   .font4 {font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
   .font5 {font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;}

   var fonts = ['.font1', '.font2', '.font3', '.font4', '.font5'];

really hope someone can help.

code is as follows;

```
<button onclick="run()">Test</button>
<div id="output"/>

var fonts = ['Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Georgia', 'Tahoma', 'Verdana'];
var weights = ['normal', 'bold', 'lighter'];
var sizes = ['16px', '20px', '24px', '36px', '40px'];

var choose = function(arr) {
return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
};
var output = document.getElementById("output");

window.run = function() {
var text = choose(sizes) + ' ' + choose(weights) + ' '  +  choose(fonts);
output.innerHTML = '<div class="randomFont" style="font: ' + text + '">' + text +      '</div>';
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/bwsvy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can attach an event listener to the window `load` event:

   ```
   window.addEventListener('load', run, false);
   ```

   Better yet, if the browsers you're targeting support it, you could use `DOMContentLoaded`, which will not wait for images, stylesheets, and other less-essential resources to load:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run, false);
   ```

   You could even use a combination of the two: attach to both, and in `run`, only do it when it has not already been done.
2. You can find all of the elements with a given `class` using [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName). You can then iterate over the returned collection and give a random font to each of those.
3. (and 4.) Rather than constructing some HTML and a CSS string, you could instead use the `style` property for the weights and sizes. For example:

   ```
   element.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
   ```

   For the font family, select one of your classes and append a space and then it to the element's `className` property:

   ```
   element.className += ' ' + fontFamilyClass;
   ```

## [Try it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/xG3VY/)

Comment: also, when i change it to document.getElementsByClassName, it seems to break?

Comment: @user1106295: I added a JSFiddle example of it.

Comment: perfect! is there a way to add in the text plugin that resizes the text depending on the screen size?

Comment: @user1106295: I don't know which plugin you're talking about.

Comment: sorry no problem, can you just tell me how to add a separate variable for font-style? e.g adding italic, normal, bold etc in classes called style1, sty;e 2 etc etc?

Comment: im trying to use a google font called open sans, my problem is i dont think im putting the weights in correctly, or they are not responding. i need it to like like this, andym.ca/ps_version.jpg, i have options like 800italic, would that work in fontweight? i just need to get the styles working for this font http://www.google.com/webfonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Reenie+Beanie

Comment: @user1106295: Remove my `output.style.` lines and replace them with the kind of line I used for the font family (`output.className +=`).

Comment: amazing! and my last question i swear! is it possible if i wanted the user of this to be able to add multiply classes for each array, without keeping having to add the "* 2 + 1)"? so if i add another class i would have to change this, if there a way where it will do it automatically?

Comment: @user1106295: You could, instead of just generating numbers to use as part of the class name, use an array of classes to add. Then you could use your `choose` function as before but like this: `output.className += ' ' + choose(someArrayOfClasses);`

Comment: yes, but i would still need to jkeep adding in the classes into the array i create, how would i create and array that will look through each class by adding +1 to each.
That way i could keep adding classes for each, and the array would just keep adding one in each array?

Answer (score 0):

You are building the style as a shorthand, but the order you specify them in is wrong the size should be before the family. 
The proper way would be `<div style=bold 16px Verdana></div>`

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7egCK/2/

If you would like this to happen on load simply execute your html render function in onLoad event of the Body

```
<body onLoad="run()">
```

Comment: Putting everything in `font` is a valid CSS shorthand, although I think the order is wrong. [Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/v8neB/)

Comment: true it is, I never remember the shorthands because you have to remember the order. :)

Comment: thanks, but how do i do the following? if i have multiply divs with the same class, i need the text in any of te div's to change to a random font etc. so i need to change it to clas sinstead of div, and i also need to change the output to read whats in each div?

Comment: so the divs are already in the page? and you want to change all of them to random font...is that correct?

Comment: yes, i have this right now http://jsfiddle.net/xG3VY/ but im trying to use a google font called open sans, my problem is i dont think im putting the weights in correctly, or they are not responding.
i need it to like like this, http://andym.ca/ps_version.jpg